# How does perf associate events to functions?

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel, perf

More precisely how does the perf tool associate PMU events to functions
i already realized that when the kernel perf subsystem records the event counters it also records the Program Counter (PC) so it can associate the count to a function.

However to really get fine grain result, you need to sample the counters in a very high rate, otherwise you may associate counters to a group of functions.
But reading the counters and writing the sampled data (counters, PC, call-stack) to the perf mmap space is very intrusive.

I read in some sources that this sampling only happens when the PMU counters overflow, but this is can be very coarse unless i am setting the counters to overflow very quickly

what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`perf record`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-record.1.html) is [statistical profiling tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)#Statistical_profilers), it either program hardware performance event monitor unit (PMU) to overflow after some number of counts (for example with `-e cycles -c 1000000` write -1000000 to counter and enable counting cycles; with `-F` or without freq/period argument it will autotune value), on overflow interrupt perf will reprogram it for next count. So it will have several hundreds or few thousands events per second. Or it can use OS timer interrupt (`-e task-clock`) to get periodic samples. On every sample (or on interrupt from hardware PMU) perf will record current PC (EIP) and/or callstack; and it does not record current value of counter (check full dump of data stored in the  perf.data with [`perf script` or `perf script -D`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-script.1.html); or [code of sample event dumping](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/util/session.c?v=4.8#L1071) - there is `sample->ip` but not current count of PMU).

[`perf report`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-report.1.html) will parse perf.data to get all PC recorded in it. It will count how many times each PC was sampled to build histogram `[PC] -> sample_count`. Every PC will be associated with the exact function it belongs (perf report will parse memory map, as `mmap` events are recorded in perf.data too, open every binary used, find symbols table of every binary).

Actual code of `perf report` is in `linux/tools/perf/builtin-report.c`: [`cmd_report`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-report.c?v=4.8#L663)/[`__cmd_report`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-report.c?v=4.8#L520) -> [`perf_session__process_events`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-report.c?v=4.8#L547) -> some magic -> [`process_sample_event`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-report.c?v=4.8#L141) to record all mentioned in perf.data `ip` (PC) values with `hist_entry_iter__add(&iter, &al, rep->max_stack, rep);` into histogram with [`hist_iter__report_callback`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-report.c?v=4.8#L96):

```
hist_entry__inc_addr_samples(he, evsel->idx, al->addr);
. . . (perf/util/annotate.c) __symbol__inc_addr_samples
  611         h->addr[offset]++;
```

Then it will output collected histogram with [`report__browse_hists`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-report.c?v=4.8#L436) -> [`perf_evlist__tty_browse_hists`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-report.c?v=4.8#L357) -> `hists__fprintf_nr_sample_events(hists, rep, evname, stdout);`.

Every sample is already associated with exact function (and bit inexact instruction inside it because of out-of-order nature of CPUs and not-precise PMU overflow event), and this is how [statistical profiling works](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Statistical_Profiling). When your program runs for short time (less than second) and/or you have too low sampling frequency, you may have few samples recorded in `perf.data`. But if you has more than several hundreds samples, you can find most cpu-heavy functions (they probably have [pareto rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) and runs for around several dozens percents of program run time. When you want to see smaller functions (around several percent of running time), use thousands or tens or thousands samples and do some statistical estimations (you will not get correct percent of function which runs for 0.1% of time when you have 100 or 1000 samples).

Comment: So, basically the count is ignored and it just samples occurrences of PCs during  overflow events. I can see how that works when the event is CPU cycles and with enough samples. But how does that  work when the event is cache misses for example. Is it guaranteed that the ovewflow events in cache misses will also represent a good approximation

Comment: Basically in sampling count is zero on irq. All events works using the same PMU unit, they only setup it for different event id. Cache misses to nearest caches (each core has own L1 and L2 caches) can be still registered almost accurately (but in some architectures event may skid to the USE of loaded value, from LOAD commands). Offcore/uncore events are not so easy as they are in some resource with is shared between cores and uses global PMUs; to associate them special synthetic events of local PMU can be used to correlate counts and route interrupts (but I completely misunderstand this part).

Comment: You may also check presentations from Andi Kleen who writes huge parts of perf for x86 and writes pmu-tools (intel-specific wrapper for perf - https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools); for example http://halobates.de/modern-pmus-yokohama.pdf "Modern CPU Performance Analysis on Linux", 2011 - "*Basic operation of a PMU .. Event code to enable counting for an event • Interrupt when threshold reached: allows sampling... Classic profiling
• Follow the Pareto principle 80-20 (or 90-10 according to
Knuth)
• Use sampling with cycle counter
• Identify hottest code*".